# Como formatear fecha recibida en ajax desde una api rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, aplicación-web

estoy consumiendo una API y los datos recibidos con ajax lo pongo en una datatable
La hora me salen asi 1899-12-31T02:32:27.000Z
y la quiero asi 09:52:13 pm, si alguno podria ayudarme por favor, estaria muy agradecido

**Este es mi codigo**

````
  $.ajax({
  
  url: 'www.apirest.com',
  method: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data){
  
    var table = $(tvHorario).DataTable( {
          lengthChange: true,
          language: idioma,
          scrollY:400,
          order: [[ 6, "desc" ]],
          scrollCollapse: true,
          paging: false,  
          data: data,                 
          columns: [
 
                {"data": "fecha" },
                {"data": "entrada" },
                {"data": "salida" }
                  ]
              }); 
          table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );   
      } 
  });```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solamente te interesa la hora y necesitas que sea en formato am/pm puedes usar este snippet adaptado a tu caso:

```js
function formatDate(dateString) {
  var date = new Date(dateString);
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

test = '1899-12-31T02:32:27.000Z'
console.log(formatDate(test));
```